# Codename One layout disconfigured

Tags: css, layout, codenameone

I have been using CN1 for my Android application normally with an external style sheet in NetBeans.

Now, every time I run the application the styling gets dis-configured, like labels changing their background and text alignment, etc.

In the screenshot, the title command's background is supposed to be transparent (turns white) and the material command on the buttons is supposed to be white (turns black).

Making changes in the theme editor brings the styling back to normal, but only until the next simulation. The APK only loads with the wrong layout.

The file theme.res seems to getting deleted and recreated for some reason.

Is there any way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the CSS plugin? What are you doing in the project?

Comment: Yes, I use the CSS plugin. I use it for styling buttons and labels. Nothing out of the ordinary that didn't work in the past. I also use a title command, styled with the standard theme editor. The command style also dis-configures randomly. When I make a small change to a component in the theme editor, all styling gets back to normal, but as soon as I reload the screen, the title command and the labels dis-configure again. On the screen itself, there are 6 buttons, a spanlabel and a title command.

Comment: Just added a screenshot for clarification. Title command originally transparent, turns white, material icons originally white, turn black.

Comment: * title command's BACKGROUND turns white, supposed to be transparent

Comment: We've made a lot of changes to the CSS support so maybe something broke. The new update we released has a new CSS mode in Codename One Settings, did you activate it? If so I suggest backing up your project before doing that. I'm guessing that this might be related to theme layering which is a tricky subject. With new CSS projects we recommend using either CSS or the Designer never both

Comment: No, I did not activate the new CSS support. How does the new css support work? Does it already create a directory and file when it is activated? If have deleted the TitleCommand UIID from the theme editor and moved it to the css file, what brought my original styling back.

Comment: We have a blog post about that new CSS support coming out today. These things with layered themes are very hard to track down as there are too many moving parts, if you can isolate this into a test case it will help but it might be worthwhile to migrate completely to CSS with the new support.

Comment: Will migrate to the new CSS support when I start a new project. Eager to read your post. Many thanks for your time and patience.